# process transaction function paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am building an e-commerce application through video tuition.

I have a `process_transaction` function that parses `PayPal` tx params from the URL upon a successful purchase and populates an 'orders' table in `phpMyAdmin` 4.8.0.

Previously, if your refreshed my `thank_you.php` page the orders continue to populate my 'orders' table (as there was previously no session destroy built into the aforementioned function).

The problem is, the code suggested to prevent such by our tutor for this function does not work. When run, the 'orders' table is no longer populating from the transactions nor is session_destroy operational.

I was wondering what is wrong with the function.

**thank_you.php**

```
<?php require_once("../resources/config.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../resources/cart.php"); ?> 
<?php include('../resources/templates/front/header.php') ?>   
<?php process_transaction(); ?> 
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">THANK YOU</h1>
    <h3>Nippon will get your products shipped today</h3>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<?php include('../resources/templates/front/footer.php') ?>
```

**cart.php** (not working properly - does not persist orders in db, or session destroy)

```
<?php

function process_transaction() {
    if(isset($_GET['tx'])) {
        $amount = $_GET['amt']; // get amount
        $currency = $_GET['cc'];
        $transaction = $_GET['tx']; // 
        $status = $_GET['st']; // get status ie completed
        $total = 0;
        $item_quantity = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
            if($value > 0 ) {
                if (substr($name, 0, 8) == "product_") {
                    $length = strlen($name); 
                    $id = substr($name, 8, $length);
                    $send_order = query("INSERT INTO orders (order_amount,order_transaction,order_status,order_currency) VALUES('{$amount}','{$transaction}','{$status}','{$currency}')");
                    $last_id = last_id(); 
                    confirm($send_order); 

                    $query = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($id) . " ");
                    confirm($query);

                    while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
                        $product_price = $row['product_price'];
                        $product_title = $row['product_title'];
                        $sub = $row['product_price'] * $value;
                        $item_quantity += $value;
                        $insert_report = query("INSERT INTO reports (product_id, order_id, product_title, product_price,product_quantity) VALUES ('{$id}','{$last_id}','{$product_title}','{$product_price}','{$value}')");
                        confirm($insert_report);
                    }
                    $total += $sub;
                    echo $item_quantity;
                }
            }
        }
        session_destroy();
    } else {
        redirect("index.php");
    }
}
```

**functions.php**

```
function query($sql) {
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}    

function fetch_array($result) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
}

function escape_string($string) {
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$string);  
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show the `query()`, `escape_string()` and `fetch_array()` functions ?

Comment: certainly. give me 5 minutes thanks

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ I have placed these above now.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection, you should use different methods this should never be used in production, you don't know if the content of your $_GET vars will be malicious and run some unexpected queries in your db

Comment: I know, that is not the issue at this stage in the dev mode, that will be resolved later before production

Comment: I dont understand your problem. 'refreshed my thank_you.php page the orders continue to pile into my 'orders' table in my db as there was previously'. If you explain a little bit more of what's your problem but you just copy pasted all your files

Comment: it is a bad practice to write unsecure code and then add security. it is better to write secure code directly.

Comment: `session_destroy()` does not empty `$_SESSION`. you may need to add `$_SESSION = array();` as stated here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: There are a number of things that look odd to me, first the order insert shouldn't depend on the session, you are already receiving the variables via get. Secondly, it checks the session for products for the name value of `product_` which seems like a bad structure for storing your items in the session. Lastly, the reason why you can reload the page and the order keep being added is because it is relying on the get variables - this is a very bad idea for an e-commerce system. In all honesty, the whole set up looks very poorly laid out and very dangerous.